# How do I check if any element of a vector is in the value of a hashmap?

Tags: clojure

I have vectors with a list of tiles and a map of adjacent tiles (like a graph). I want to return true if there are any adjacent tiles and false if there are no adjacent tiles. So comparing `[1 3 19]` should be true, because `(adjacents 1)` contains 3. While comparing `[1 14 19]` should be false because `(adjacents 1)` does not contain 14 or 19, `(adjacents 14)` does not contain 1 or 19 and `(adjacents 19)` does not contain 1 or 14.

So tile 1 is adjacent to tiles 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

```
    (def adjacents
               {1 [2 3 4 5 6 7]
                2 [1 3 7 8 9 10]
                3 [1 2 4 10 11 12]
                4 [1 3 5 12 13 14]
                5 [1 4 6 14 15 16]
                6 [1 5 7 16 17 18]
                7 [1 2 6 8 18 19]
                8 [2 7 8 18]
                9 [2 8 10]
                10 [2 3 9 11]
                11 [3 10 12]
                12 [3 4 11 13]
                13 [4 12 14]
                14 [4 5 13 15]
                15 [5 14 16]
                16 [5 6 15 17]
                17 [6 16 18]
                18 [6 7 17 19]
                19 [7 8 18]})
```

I've thought about using map, but I can't figure out what function to put inside it. Also thought about turning the values of the hashmap into a set and the vector into a set then comparing the intersection but I'm not thinking about this correctly.

Comment: Is `[8]` a valid input and does it return `true`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. No tiles should be adjacent to themselves. That's a bug in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that loops over the possible pairs of adjacent vertices and checks if any of the pairs are adjacent:

```
(defn any-adjacent? [adjmap vertices]
  (seq (for [a vertices
             b vertices
             x (adjmap a)
             :when (= x b)]
         a)))

(any-adjacent? adjacents [1 3 19])
;; => (1 3)

(any-adjacent? adjacents [1 14 19])
;; => nil
```

If you use *sets* instead of vectors as suggested by @amalloy, that is

```
(def adjacents {1 #{7 4 6 3 2 5},
                2 #{7 1 3 9 10 8}
                ...
                })
```

it is possible to implement more concisely and with better time complexity:

```
(defn any-adjacent? [adjmap vertices]
  (seq (for [a vertices
             b vertices
             :when ((adjmap a) b)]
         a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all the adjacent tiles with `mapcat`, then test whether that collection contains any of your tiles using `some`:

```clj
(defn any-adjacent [graph tiles]
  (some (set tiles)
        (mapcat graph tiles)))

(any-adjacent adjacents [1 3 19])
; => 3

(any-adjacent adjacents [1 14 19])
; => nil

(any-adjacent adjacents [8])
; => 8
```

If the return value needs to be Boolean:

```
(defn any-adjacent? [graph tiles]
  (some? (some (set tiles)
               (mapcat graph tiles))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main part of the solution will be function [`some`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some).

For each number in the given vector `v`, you have to find a vector of adjacent elements: `(graph %)` and then compare this vector to other elements in `v`, using second `some`: `(some (disj (set v) %) (graph %))`. So, I think this should work:

```
(defn any-adjacent? [graph v]
  (some #(some (disj (set v) %)
               (graph %))
        v))
```

Tests:

```
(def adjacents
  {1 [2 3 4 5 6 7]
   2 [1 3 7 8 9 10]
   3 [1 2 4 10 11 12]
   4 [1 3 5 12 13 14]
   5 [1 4 6 14 15 16]
   6 [1 5 7 16 17 18]
   7 [1 2 6 8 18 19]
   8 [2 7 8 18]
   9 [2 8 10]
   10 [2 3 9 11]
   11 [3 10 12]
   12 [3 4 11 13]
   13 [4 12 14]
   14 [4 5 13 15]
   15 [5 14 16]
   16 [5 6 15 17]
   17 [6 16 18]
   18 [6 7 17 19]
   19 [7 8 18]})

(any-adjacent? adjacents [1 3 19])
=> 3

(any-adjacent? adjacents [1 14 19])
=> nil
```

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient, as well as simpler, to adjust the graph data structure to contain sets instead of vectors. `(some #(some ...))` is a nested loop, and it's quite sad to have quadratic-time performance for an operation like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. It turns the list of locations and the values of the map into sets then takes the intersection. If the intersection is empty, there is no overlap so nothing is adjacent. By using `map` on the hashmap, it pulls all the relevant values out.

```
(defn adjacent?
  [locations-v neighbors-m]
  (let [loc-set (set locations-v)
        neighbors-set (set (flatten (map neighbors-m locations-v)))]
    (seq (set/intersection loc-set neighbors-set))))
```